Multiple results of same action "Killing a brahmana" in garuda purana
I was reading The Motilal Banarsidass translation of Garuda Purana by J.L. Shastri And at page 727, point 61 they said "The killer of a brähmana attains the form of a deer, horse, pig or camel." And at point 63 "The slayer of a brähmana suffers from consumption."
And then i checked Garuda Purana By MN Dutt and at page 296, "The killer of brahmana after passing through the bodies of a dog, an ass and a camel...."
So there are three different things i can observe by reading all.
Which one is right ?
